# Disabling submit button stops form from being submitted PHP / Javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I think I got a classic problem but I was not able to find a working solution so far.

I have got a form , the user clicks "Send" and everything works fine using a PRG pattern and doing both client-side and server-side validation.

The problem arises when any user (let's assume he entered valid inputs) clicks more then once quickly before the server script ends its execution...

I do not get any duplicated entry because I took care of that but the browser does not go to my "thanks for submitting page".
Instead it re-submits the same page with the same values and what I get are the custom errors I set to warn the user he is trying to enter details already stored in the database. The details sent in the first place are all in the database but the user has no chance to know that.

I tried to disable the submit button on a submit event using jQuery but in that case the data are not submitted.

HTML

```
   <div id="send-button-container">
   <input id="send-emails" type="submit" name="send_emails" value="Send"/>
   </div>
```

jQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#mail-form').submit(function(){
        $('#send-emails').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
   });
```

I am wondering if I can force a submission using Javascript after disabling the button and also how to deal with UAs with Javascript disabled

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you abort the ajax request if one is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this means you are depending on the value of the submit button to service the request?  That is you are checking

```
$_REQUEST['send_emails'] == 'Send';
```

This is not good practice.  You should never depend on the value of the submit button because that is the just what is displayed to the user.  Instead, you should add a hidden input that contains the event you want to fire.  After the form is submitted, you don't need to care what the value of the submit button is and you can disable it.  All other non-disabled data in the form is still submitted.

You can indeed force the submission after disabling the button.

```
$(function () {
   $("#mail-form").submit(function () {
      $("#send-emails").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      window.location = '?' + $("#mail-form").serialize() + '&send_mails=Send';
      return false;
   });
});
```

Server side set a $_SESSION variable that keeps track of the last time they made a submission and block submissions within a certain time.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST['send_emails'])) {
   if (isset($_SESSION['mail_sent'])
   && strtotime($_SESSION['mail_sent']) < strtotime('5 seconds ago')
   ) {
      redirect_to_thanks();
   }
   do_post();
}

function do_post() {
   if (do_validate()) {
      $_SESSION['mail_sent'] = time();
      redirect_to_thanks();
   }
   else {
      yell_at_user_a_lot();
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Normally one would check which button was clicked without depending on the value of the clicked button. For example, you may have two submit buttons with value "Send Email" and "Destroy World" (`name`d `send_email` and `destroy_world`). If the user clicks the "Send Email" button, the form data will contain `send_email=Send Email`, but won't contain `destroy_world` at all. The application can simply check for the presence of `send_email` to determine what to do, and thus avoid a tragedy.

Comment: -1 Also the forced submission is a GET, which isn't much good if the server is expecting a POST...

Answer (score 3):

Depending on server-side language, the submit button being disabled could cause problems.  This is because disabled elements are not POSTed to the server.  Languages like ASP.NET require the button value to be submitted so it knows what event handler to fire.  What I usually do is *hide* the submit button, and insert a disabled dummy button after it, which appears identical to the user. Then in your onsubmit handler, you can return false and submit the form programmatically...

```
$('#mail-form').submit(function(){
  var btn = $('#send-emails');
  var disBtn = $("<input type='button'/>").val(btn.val()).attr("disabled", "disabled");

  btn.hide().after(disBtn);
  this.submit();
  return false;
});
```

Contradictory to the other up-voted answers, please note that you do *not* need to explicitly return true from your submit handler for natural form submission: http://jsfiddle.net/XcS5L/3/

Comment: This will still allow the form to be submitted by pressing enter, though. It might be better to completely remove the submit button and save its value in a hidden field.

Comment: @Tgr I don't see a problem with the Enter key.  Regardless, fixing it would be as simple as having a global variable set to true after the first submit.  Then check the variable in the handler before calling `this.submit()`.  Easy.

Comment: This does not work though...I still do not go to the the "thank you page"...I used tandu(below) advice to use a hidden input field and it works...

Comment: @Mirko Well "does not work" has never been a reasonable explanation.  This actually works just fine!  And tandu's answer is not even doing a form submission, it does a GET request, which is actually quite stupid.  But, whatever suits your fancy.

Comment: The form it is still not submitted using just jQuery. What I did, actually, was inserting a hidden input field and checking in the POST array for that value. I still disable the button using Javascript, but I do not rely any more on the "submit" button for the submission. It works ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return true`; You could try this if u want a simple button to submit the form.

```
$(function(){
   $('#submitID').one('click',function(){
    $('#formTobeSubmitted').submit();
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
 })
});
```

Comment: This won't disable the button when the user submits the form through other means, e.g. by pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

On server side, generate a random number into each form, store the number when the form is submitted, and discard the submit if that number has already been stored earlier. When the user has disabled javascript, this is the best you can do. (Concurrency issues can be tricky as the two identical requests are handled at the same time - make sure you use some sort of locking mechanism, such as a table with a unique field or the [flock()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) command in PHP.)

On browser side, just set a flag when the form is submitted, and discard all later submits:

```
$('#mail-form').submit(function() {
    if ($(this).data('submitted') {
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).data('submitted', true).addClass('submitted');
    }
});
```

You can use the `submitted` class to make the buttons gray or something. This has a few advantages to simply disabling them; Josh already said one. Another is that Firefox likes to remember disabled states when you hit refresh, which can cause your users getting stuck in certain situations.